# Draw a line segment in a fragment shader

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm struggling to understand the following code, the idea is to draw a simple segment in a fragment shader. I tried to decompose it but I still don't get the ??? line.
It would be awesome to have a nice explanation. I couldn't find anything on SO or Google.

```
float lineSegment(vec2 p, vec2 a, vec2 b) {
    float thickness = 1.0/100.0;

    vec2 pa = p - a;
    vec2 ba = b - a;

    float h = clamp( dot(pa,ba)/dot(ba,ba), 0.0, 1.0 );
    // ????????
    float idk = length(pa - ba*h);

    return smoothstep(0.0, thickness, idk);
}
```

Original code comes from [TheBookOfShaders.](https://thebookofshaders.com/edit.php?log=160414041542)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the line is defined by the points `a`, `b`, and `p` is the point to evaluate, then `pa` is the vector that goes from point `a` to point `p` and `ba` the vector from `a` to `b`.

Now, `dot(ba, ba)` is equal to `length(ba) ^ 2` and `dot(pa,ba) / length(ba)` is the projection of the vector pa over your line. Then, `dot(pa,ba)/dot(ba,ba)` is the projection normalized over the length of your line. That value is clamped between 0 and 1 so your projection will always be in between the point that define your line.

Then on `length(pa - ba * h)`, `ba * h` is equal to `dot(pa,ba) / length(ba)`  which was the projection of your point over your line, now clamped between points a and b. The subtraction `pa - ba * h` results in a vector that represents the minimum distance between your line and point `p`. Using the length of that vector and comparing it against the thickness you can determine whether the point falls inside the line you want to draw.